# RTC Client Java API: How do I get the state of the user's version before the merge from an IChange merge state?

Tags: version-control, java, rational-team-concert

I'm using the [Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/products/rational-team-concert/) (RTC) client Java API to work with the RTC SCM.  I have an `IChange` instance, `change`, which I obtained from an `IChangeSet` instance, `changeset`, via a call to `changeSet.changes()`.  I use `change.mergeStates()` to get a list of the `change`'s merge states.  From the `IChange.mergeStates()` Javadoc:

> Consider this list to be the proposed versions that were merged with
>   the before state. The after state is the versionable after the merge
>   has been completed. The state of the user's version (mine) before the
>   merge is not recorded in this IChange. It can be found in the IChange
>   of the previous IChangeSet state.

How do I get the `IChange` of the previous `IChangeSet` state?  I tried calling `changeSet.getMergePredecessorState()` to get the the previous `IChangeSet` state.  However, it always returns `null`.